# A heap has been corrupted Exception C++

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, runtime, heap-corruption

running this piece of code cause heap to be corrupted

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public:
    char* charArr;
    int *intArr1;
    int *intArr2;
    int *intArr3;
    X()
    {
        charArr = new char[] { 5, 5, 5, 5 };
        intArr1 = new int[] { -10, -10, -10 };
        intArr2 = new int[] { -20, -20, -20};
        intArr3 = new int[] { -30, -30, -30};
    }
    ~X()
    {
    delete[] charArr;
    delete[] intArr1;
    delete[] intArr2;
    delete[] intArr3;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I'm use visual studio and this is the error msg:
[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce117.png)

Comment: *I'm use visual studio* -- You are??  [This link](http://rextester.com/FXYR13331) says differently.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ He does not why it does not work. That is why he came here.

Comment: @code0 Ever heard that it's necessary to provide a [MCVE] here, when asking such questions?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What I mean is that just saying it doesn't compile and posting a link is not helpful. He already posted a link to the error, so why should some one else do it?

Comment: @code0 You completely missed my point. I cannot reproduce a runtime error, the code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for clarifying. I guess the really bad comments and questions are making me very critical.

Comment: This is not funny question
and I'm not so ridiculous to send such uncompilable code.
I'm pretty sure that non of you try to compile this code on visual studio 2013
BUT this code has been compiled without any ERROR

Comment: it's not a challenge to prove who's right .. see this video [link](https://youtu.be/c3LhOWgZOTU)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual studio too. And when I try to start debugging. There are some errors when you write:

```
charArr = new char[] { 5, 5, 5, 5 };
intArr1 = new int[] { -10, -10, -10 };
intArr2 = new int[] { -20, -20, -20};
intArr3 = new int[] { -30, -30, -30};
```

I think you should write like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X
{
public:
    char* charArr;
    //int *intArr1;
    //int *intArr2;
    //int *intArr3;
    X()
    {
        charArr = new char[4];
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            charArr[i] = 5;


        //intArr1 = new int[] { -10, -10, -10 };
        //intArr2 = new int[] { -20, -20, -20};
        //intArr3 = new int[] { -30, -30, -30};
    }
    ~X()
    {
    delete[] charArr;
   // delete[] intArr1;
   // delete[] intArr2;
   // delete[] intArr3;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;

    return 0;
}
```

Then it works well.